# join data using substring from a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have a dataset `df` that looks like this:

```
mandant posnr   aufdat
9   120300001   13.01.20 00:00
9   180200017   13.02.20 00:00
9   180300010   03.02.20 00:00
```

I want to join this with another dataset present in a dictionary `newDict['second']`that looks like this:

```
mandant nr  jahr
0   1032    2016
0   1291    2016
0   5442    2016
0   5502    2016
```

Normally, I would do an inner join like this:

```
df_merged = df.merge(newDict['second'], 
                                        left_on=['nrkreis_nr'],
                                        right_on=['nr'],
                                        how='inner')
```

However, now I need to perform a join using two conditions. The first is mentioned above and the second is

```
newDict['second'].jahr = year of (df.aufdat)
```

Values from the `df.aufdat` col loook like this originally `13.01.20 00:00`. How can I use two join conditions together in this case, especially because I need to join on the basis of a substring and not the full string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new column called `jahr` in `df` by converting to datetimes and [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and add this columns in both `left_on` and `right_on` parameters:

```
df_merged = (df.assign(jahr = pd.to_datetime(df['aufdat'], format='%d.%m.%y %H:%M').dt.year)
              .merge(newDict['second'], 
                     left_on=['nrkreis_nr','jahr'],
                     right_on=['nr','jahr']))
```